Carbon::now() no obtiene la fecha correcta
Tengo un proyecto desarrollado en Laravel 10 y que acabo de actualizar a Laravel 11. Tras realizar la actualización todo funciona de forma correcta excepto la librería Carbon.
Ejemplo:
Si ejecuto la función Carbon::now() en lugar de obtener 21-11-2024 me devuelve 26-02-2025.
He revisado el archivo .ENV y la configuración es correcta, no ha cambiado:
APP_TIMEZONE=Europe/Madrid
APP_LOCALE=es
Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque puede estar ocurriendo esto?
Un saludo.

En app.php como está configurada la zona ? Mismo caso con el php.ini revisa ese igual.

Hola. ya he dado con el problema. No estaba funcionando de forma correcta porque utilizaba una misma instancia para diferentes operaciones y la fecha no se actualizaba.  Gracias por la ayuda
